# Solving sparse system over GF(q)

Tags: linear-algebra, sparse-matrix, finite-field

I am interested in solving large (`n` up to 10^5 or maybe even 10^6) rectangular (maybe 10% more columns than rows) sparse (< 10 nonzeros per row) systems `Ax = b` over a finite field `GF(q)` (`q` might be a prime near 1000 or so).  From the literature, it looks like block Lanczos methods might be the most appropriate.

I have Linbox which is supposed to have such methods, but have been unable to get the BlockLanczos solver there to work, and [one report](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/linbox-use/iu2B1ei4IxM) says that this has been broken since 2003.  The `SparseElimination` method does work, but it seems that this will not work well for large `n` because of fill-in of the matrix.

So, what is available that does work for such problems?

Comment: I'm not an expert in numerical computing, but here is a more recent code:  http://seldon.sourceforge.net/doc-5.0/file.php?name=computation/solver/iterative/Cgs.cxx  It's not clear if hit handles finite fields. Iterative methods like Gauss-Jacobi are also useful for large systems.

Comment: You may have better luck getting an answer on http://mathoverflow.net or http://math.stackexchange.com .

Comment: @Gene: Thanks.  It seems Seldon is for numerical computations over real or complex numbers, not exact computations over finite fields.  By "Gauss-Jacobi" do you mean Gauss-Siedel or Jacobi? It's not at all clear that these methods can be adapted to finite fields (although Lanczos and conjugate-gradient methods can).

Comment: @dg99: Thanks.  I found the linbox-use newsgroup, and got an answer there: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/linbox-use/gSA4oT7M2nM

Comment: Julia supports finite fields. https://github.com/Nemocas/AbstractAlgebra.jl/blob/master/docs/src/finfield.md, http://nemocas.github.io/Nemo.jl/latest/. There are quick ways to solve them that are implicitly derived.

Answer (score 0):

Julia supports finite fields. My professor had a short [how to on his.](https://github.com/johnfgibson/whyjulia/blob/master/5-julia-goes-beyond.ipynb) It's on line 37. The LU decomp and other commands are built in and derived from the GF type.